# Algorithm to check to output largest value in array or display if empty

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to practice algorithms before i start my undergrad in computer science and i am struggling really bad to write algorithms. I understand them once i've been taught them and break them down but when I am trying to do my own, it fails miserable. I am trying a exercise question in a programming textbook, where i have an array and i have to output the largest value or if the array is empty, i have to display -1.

This was the best i can come up with but it still falls way short. Any pointers on what exactly I'm doing wrong.

```
 for(i = 0;i < array.length-1;i++)
     if(array[i] == 0){
         empty = true;
         n = -1;
         System.out.println(n);
     }else{
         largest = array[0];
         if(array[i] > largest){
             largest = array[i];
             System.out.println(array[i]);
         }
     }
```

I see that -1 displayed 10 times but i have found no solution for this and if the array is full, it provides me one then one value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're struggling with algorithms, it helps sometimes not to look at them as algorithms but real-world problems.

Say you are in a shop buying cheese and your task is to pick a pack of cheese which has the latest expiration date. Now imagine the situation: standing at the cheese section looking for the best yummy cheese...

1. First, you look if there is any. If not, return empty handed.
2. If there are some packs, go through them looking for the best.  You've got probably only one hand free, holding the basket in the other one, so...

   - Initially, pick the first cheese
   - Then go through the packs one by one. If you find cheese better than you have in your hand, put the one you're holding down and take the better one.

Now, let's put this to a programing language:

```
int[] cheeseExpirations = new int[] { ... };
if (cheeseExpirations.length == 0) {
    System.out.println(-1); // no cheese :(
} else {
    int myCheese = cheeseExpirations[0];                 // take the first pack; better a sparrow in the hand than a pigeon on the roof...
    for (int i = 0; i < cheeseExpirations.length; i++) { // idiomatic array iteration
        int currentCheese = cheeseExpirations[i];
        if (currentCheese > myCheese ) {                 // found a better one
            myCheese = currentCheese;                    // just take it
        }
    }
    System.out.println(bestCheese);
}
```

Is it clearer now? Like Richard Feynman said, using your imagination and examples is important:

> I had a scheme, which I still use today when somebody is explaining something that I'm trying to understand: I keep making up examples.
>
> For instance, the mathematicians would come in with a terrific theorem, and they're all excited. As they're telling me the conditions of the theorem, I construct something which fits all the conditions. You know, you have a set (one ball)-- disjoint (two balls). Then the balls turn colors, grow hairs, or whatever, in my head as they put more conditions on.
>
> Finally they state the theorem, which is some dumb thing about the ball which isn't true for my hairy green ball thing, so I say "False!" [and] point out my counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(array.length == 0){
     empty = true;
     n = -1;
     System.out.println(n);
 }else{
     largest = array[0];
     for(i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
         if(array[i] > largest){
             largest = array[i];
     }
     System.out.println(largest);
 }
```

First what i did is check if the array is empty. If it is then skip the else and output the -1. If the array is not empty set the largest to the first element and then loop through all other elements. Noticed I changed i = 1 because element 0 is already the largest. Also I removed the -1 to the array length because i will stop 1 before the length (which will be the last index of final element). Finally I moved the print of the largest value outside of the if statement and for loop so that it only gets printed once at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the length of the array in each loop. This means it won't be checked unless the array has some object, which is just what we don't want.
But, in fact, you are not checking the array length:

`if(array[i] == 0)` tests **if the item of array at index `i` is 0**. To test the length of the array, you have to do `if (array.length > 0)`. Remember you have to do this **before the for loop**, so it would be something like this:

```
if(array[i] == 0){
     empty = true;
     n = -1;
     System.out.println(n);
}
for(i = 0;i < array.length-1;i++)
     largest = array[0];
     if(array[i] > largest){
         largest = array[i];
         System.out.println(array[i]);
     }
 }
```

But, in each loop you are reassigning `largest` to the first array element, which breaks the algorithm. So you must move that line **before the for loop**.

```
if(array[i] == 0){
     empty = true;
     n = -1;
     System.out.println(n);
}
largest = array[0];
for(i = 0;i < array.length-1;i++)
     if(array[i] > largest){
         largest = array[i];
         System.out.println(array[i]);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

```
if(array[i] == 0)
```

does not check if the array is empty, it checks if the value stored at index i of the array is equal to zero.  You probably want something like:

```
if(array != null && array.length == 0) { 
    return -1;
}
```

**before the for loop executes**.

The rest of your code looks close.  The print statement inside of the else clause is unnecessary.  You just need to return the value of largest after the for loop executes.

Answer (score 0):

This code is rather strange in general. Why do you consider an array empty as soon as you reach an element that is 0? And why do you continue search, if the array is empty? Last but not least: why do you ignore the last element in the array?

There are plenty of solutions for this that are a lot simpler:

Without any java-api:

```
if(array.length == 0)
    return -1;

int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
    if(max < array[i])
        max = array[i];

return max;
```

A lazy solution using [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29) (not exactly elegant, but short)

```
Arrays.sort(array);
return array[array.length - 1];
```

Using java8:

```
return Arrays.stream(array).min((a , b) -> new Integer(a).compareTo(b)).orElse(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at your code

```
for(i = 0;i < array.length-1;i++)//You will never reach the last number
 if(array[i] == 0){//Here you check if the first item equals zero. Gives error if there is no first item.
     empty = true;//why do you need this, you never use it.
     n = -1;
     System.out.println(n);
 }else{
     largest = array[0];//Why setting largest, do dont know if it is actually bigger
     if(array[i] > largest){
         largest = array[i];
         System.out.println(array[i]);
     }
 }
```

Improved version:

```
largest = -1;//set it by default
for(i = 0;i < array.length;i++)//if length is 10 iMax = 9, which is the tenth item.
    if(array[i]>largest){//if larger set the new value
        largest = array[i];
    }   
 }
 System.out.println(largest);//print the largest number.
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the array is empty

```
if(array != null && array.length == 0) {
```

If it is print -1

```
    System.out.println(-1 + "");
}
```

Now you are ready to go through the array. But before you do create a variable that will keep track of the largest value. I set it to the first element in the array (since we know that it has at least one element since we already determined that it isn't empty)

```
else {
    int largest = array[0];
```

Then, loop through the array

```
    for(i = 0;i < array.length-1;i++) {
```

Get every element one at a time using `i` to access the ith element

```
        int current = array[i];
```

Then compare it to the largest. If it's greater than the largest so far, save it as the largest.

```
        if (current>largest) {
            current = largest;
        }
```

Keep doing that until finished looping through the array

```
    }
```

Then print out the largest

```
    System.out.println(largest + "");
}
```